# How to get Kivy to display on Adafruit pitft?

Tags: kivy, raspberry-pi3

I have a Kivy app with a simple set of controls running on Raspbian Jessie.  I can successfully get the desktop to display on the Adafruit touchscreen but no matter what I do, the Kivy app only displays on the HDMI display.  Does anyone know the trick to getting the Kivy to show on the touchscreen?  I have set the /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-fbdev.conf to:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "display"
  Driver "fbdev"
  Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
EndSection
```

Is there something specific that needs to be set in the kivy config.ini?  I've scoured the forums with no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Adafruit pitft plus](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2298)

Comment: Okey I think you need to set the resolution in .kivy/config.ini to 320x240, height and width under [graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried it with the same results.  Only outputting to the HDMI.

Comment: have you looked at this? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37484/kivy-and-3-5pitft

Comment: I had seen that.  After you sent the link, I revisited it and found that step 2 of the answer is the key (installing fbcp).  I guess I didn't go down the path originally because nowhere on the Adafruit site do they have you perform that step (unless I missed it).  I believe it comes down to the fact that the OpenGL that Kivy relies on is forced to the HDMI.  fbcp just mirrors that to the touchscreen while still displaying on the HDMI.  Nice if you want to see that but seems like a lot of overhead if you don't plan on using it in that way.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You are wellcome